# remove tick labels in Python but keep gridlines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a Python script which is producing a plot consisting of 3 subplots all in 1 column.

In the middle subplot, I currently have gridlines, but I want to remove the x axis tick labels.

I have tried

```
ax2.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
```

but this seems to remove the gridlines also.

How can I remove the tick labels and keep the gridlines please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

```
plt.grid(True)
ax2.axes.get_xaxes().set_ticks([])
```

Or maybe this:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter
ax2.axes.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(NullFormatter())
```

Comment: I tried this, but I got the same result. I already had plt.grid(), which I assume is the same. Thank you.

Comment: Bummer. Have you also tried using the formatter instead of set ticks?

Comment: I can only assume that it is due to how matplot handles the subplots. Unfortuntely I have never had much luck getting repeatibility when it comes to matplot subplots :-(